# adding onclick event to javascript dynamically created element

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically adding labels to my table when user selects combo box items, but also I want these dynamically added labels to be erasable when user clicks on them, here is my javascript function:

```
    function OnSelectedIndexChange()

{
    if (document.getElementById('cmbDestinationUser').selectedIndex != 0) {
        var spanTag = document.createElement("span");
        spanTag.id = "span1";
        var e = document.getElementById("cmbDestinationUser");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        spanTag.innerHTML = strUser;
        var TR = document.createElement('tr');
        var TD = document.createElement('td');
        TD.appendChild(spanTag);
        TR.appendChild(TD);
        document.getElementById('tblReceivers').appendChild(TR);
    }
    document.getElementById('cmbDestinationUser').selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

should I add onclick to spantag? how can I do so? should I create another function for erasing or can I define the remove operation in this function
thanks

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=243948) might be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, add the onclick to the `span`:

```
spanTag.onclick = function() {
    this.innerHTML = '';
};
```

This just clears the content of the `span`. I wasn't sure exactly what you meant by "erasing".

If you wanted to remove the `span` entirely, do this:

```
spanTag.onclick = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild( this );
};
```

---

To remove the row, do this:

```
spanTag.onclick = function() {
    var el = this;
    while( (el = el.parentNode) && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'tr' );

    if( el )
        el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
};
```

Or to make it a little clearer perhaps:

```
spanTag.onclick = function() {
    var el = this.parentNode;
    while( el ) {
       if( el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'tr' ) {
           el.parentNode.removeChild( el );
           break;
       }
       el = el.parentNode;
    } 
};
```

Comment: oh thanks I mean removing the newly creating element, I'll give it a try

Comment: thanks but I must remove the row containing this span, i.e. TR should be removed, how can I perform this?

Comment: thanks Fred, it worked just as expected, can I ask another question in this post? I want to check for duplicate labels, I mean when adding a span, its content should be checked and if it previously exists nothing happens, should I create a new post for this question?

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: That sounds like a separate issue. I'd start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use event delegation instead of setting an event handler on each node you create.

This way you can assign a single event handler to the table around the table rows, which handles all clicks on all rows and removes that row. You set it once only.

```
table.onclick = function (e) {
    var target = e.target || window.event.srcElement;

    while (target.nodeName !== 'TR') {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    target.parentNode.reamoveChild(target);
}
```